# SQL count each occurrence of case sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to return 2 columns: Day of the week and number of occurrences in that day. How would I return the number of occurrences for each day?

```
SELECT case CAST(strftime('%w', HireDate) AS INTEGER)
   WHEN 0 then 'Sunday'
   WHEN 1 then 'Monday'
   WHEN 2 then 'Tuesday'
   WHEN 3 then 'Wednesday'
   WHEN 4 then 'Thursday'
   WHEN 5 then 'Friday'
   ELSE 'Saturday' END AS 'Day of week',  AS 'Hired'
   FROM Employee;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewrite case on group by clause:

```
SELECT 
   ( case CAST(strftime('%w', HireDate) AS INTEGER)
   WHEN 0 then 'Sunday'
   WHEN 1 then 'Monday'
   WHEN 2 then 'Tuesday'
   WHEN 3 then 'Wednesday'
   WHEN 4 then 'Thursday'
   WHEN 5 then 'Friday'
   ELSE 'Saturday' END ) AS 'Day of week', 
   count(*) AS 'Hired'                              --<--here
 FROM 
   Employee
 GROUP BY                                           --<--here
   ( case CAST(strftime('%w', HireDate) AS INTEGER)
   WHEN 0 then 'Sunday'
   WHEN 1 then 'Monday'
   WHEN 2 then 'Tuesday'
   WHEN 3 then 'Wednesday'
   WHEN 4 then 'Thursday'
   WHEN 5 then 'Friday'
   ELSE 'Saturday' END );
```

Comment: can you explain why you did the count(*) AS 'Hired' and used GROUP BY?? Sorry SQL noob here.

Comment: You should to group rows by day. `count` is an aggregation function. Contains total rows for each group.